# In sql search nearest parts start and end Id by dividing it to nth parts based on data count

Tags: sql

In sql search nearest Ids by dividing it to nth parts based on data count
like my table have 8000 records and I want to fetch table data in way that it give me start and end id of 8 portions of count

like from 0 to 1000 the id is 1 to 88899 then start id should be 1 and end id should be 88899 and same for next for 1001 to 2000 the start id should be > 88899 and end id nearest to count 2000 record and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I am able to get this done in this way

```
Declare @iterations int = 8
Declare @PerPage int = (select count(Id) from iCM_Prod.dbo.UserResidents) / @iterations
select item, a.Id as StartId, b.Id as endId, 
    (
        'exec Sp_MoveAllTablesDataInChunks ''Jande''' 
        + ',' + cast( a.Id as nvarchar(500)) 
        + ',' + cast( b.Id as nvarchar(500)) 
        + ',' + cast( @iterations as nvarchar(500)) 
    ) AS Ok
from iCM_Prod.dbo.SplitDelimiterString('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9', ',')
outer apply(
    SELECT  top 1 Id
    FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Id ) AS RowNum, *
              FROM      iCM_Prod.dbo.UserResidents
            ) AS RowConstrainedResult
    WHERE   RowNum > (case when item = 1 then 0 else (item - 1) * @PerPage end)
        AND RowNum < item * @PerPage
    ORDER BY RowNum
    asc
) a

outer apply(
    SELECT  top 1 Id
    FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Id ) AS RowNum, *
              FROM      iCM_Prod.dbo.UserResidents
            ) AS RowConstrainedResult
    WHERE   RowNum > (case when item = 1 then 0 else (item - 1) * 106392 end)
        AND RowNum < item * 106392
    ORDER BY RowNum
    desc
) b
```